# webpack CLI - /usr/bin/env: node : No such file or directory

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, webpack, gitlab-ci

I use a webpack and it has this shebang in it's cli file `#! /usr/bin/env node` and it is suppose to run on a gitlab using it's CI runner with docker images.

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/bin/webpack.js

No matter of which node image I'm using it returns this error:

```
/usr/bin/env: node
: No such file or directory
npm info lifecycle @1.0.0~prod: Failed to exec prod script
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @1.0.0 prod script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional 
logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2017-09-19T21_15_51_611Z-debug.log
```

Latest docker image I used is node official (https://hub.docker.com/_/node/)
I'm even explicitly adding a symlink `ln -s /usr/local/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node` but it is still returning same error.

Comment: Could you share your webpack config file? You shouldn't need a shebang for Node there.

Comment: Do you have a space in that shebang?

Comment: I do have a space between `#!` and `/usr/bin/env node` I have other scripts that have space and they work just fine

Comment: This seems to be some other error then. What is the output of just `env` command. Also add a environment variable `NODE_DEBUG=fs,module` this will give more logs

Comment: unfortunately I can't dump `NODE_DEBUG` since I'm building this on gitlab and it has limitation for the size of build log. btw, I tried to remove space in shebang, still failing with the same error.

Comment: @Sharif as long as you're using docker images, you can still run your jobs locally (see https://bryce.fisher-fleig.org/blog/faster-ci-debugging-with-gitlabci/index.html for some complete reference) together with the `NODE_DEBUG` of your choice and see the output locally (with e.g. `docker logs`)